# socket bug in socket.io

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io

I'm trying to use the socket.io library to create a simple game. The point of the game is  to display same number to everyone connected to the website

```
var init = false
var init_pause = false
var send_message = false
var number = 0
var pause_start = 0
var paused = false

function rising_number() {
    if (!init) {
        paused = false
        number = 0
        init = true
        init_pause = false
    }
    if (number < 1000) {
        number = number + 1
    }
    else 
    {
        paused = true
        if (!init_pause) {
            pause_start = new Date().getTime()
            send_message = true
            init_pause = true
        }
        //this just waits until 2 seconds pass
        if ((new Date().getTime() - pause_start) / 1000 >= 2) {
            init = false
        }
    }
}

setInterval(rising_number, 5)

io.on("connection", socket => {
    function send_result() {
        if (!paused) {
            socket.emit('number', {number: number})
        }
        if (send_message) {
            socket.emit('number', {ended: true})
            console.log("round ended")
            send_message = false
        }
    }
    setInterval(() => send_result(), 50)
})
```

So the function `rising_number` is calculating the number that should be displayed to the users. When the number is equal to 1000, the game gets paused and the pause gets initialized so the variable `send_message` is now set to `true`. When the user is connected and `send_message` is `true` `ended: true` should be emitted. But I tried console logging the ended variable on the frontend and it gets recieved about 50% of the times, although `"round ended"` gets console logged every single time `send_message` is `true`. Why is this happening and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: `setInterval(send_result, 50)`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone still the same result :(

Comment: It probably won't work because there is a delay for websockets?